# Waiting for canvas.toDataURL() to complete before submitting blob to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf.js

I have a project requirement here using file input to accept file and display it on the canvas while at the same time processes it as a blob and send it to the backend for processing. Depending on the file type, different processes my be used instead.

If the file type is a pdf, it will be processed using pdf.js, and the pdf image will be displayed on the canvas while the file is converted into a blob and sent to the backend for processing. So far this is okay for single page pdf only, as i can straight get the canvas data into a blob and send it directly after toDataURL has finished.

However for multiple pages pdf, i'm having trouble on doing multiple toDataURL run on each page. My idea is, when i iterate each page using pdf.js's getPage, then i will display the page on the canvas, and get the canvas image as a blob and push it into an array. Once all pages have been processed and all the blobs are pushed into the array, i will send it to the backend for processing.

```
var __TOTAL_PAGES, __ISMULTIPLEPAGE, __CANVAS = undefined;
var __MULTIPAGEHOLDER = [];

function showPDF(pdf_url) {
    PDFJS.getDocument({url: pdf_url}).then(function (pdf_doc) {
        __TOTAL_PAGES = pdf_doc.numPages;
        __ISMULTIPLEPAGE = __TOTAL_PAGES > 1 ? true : false;

        // Show the first page
        for (var i = 0; i < __TOTAL_PAGES; i++){
            $('#parentId').append('<canvas id="canvas-'+(i+1)+'"></canvas>');

            showPage(i+1);
    }

    }).catch(function (error) {
    /* Insert any error handling here */
    });
}

function showPage(page_no) {
    __PDF_DOC.getPage(page_no).then(function (page) {
        /* Some setup here */

        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: /* Some value */,
            viewport: /* Some value */
        };

        // Render the page contents in the canvas
        page.render(renderContext).then(function () {

            __CANVAS = document.getElementById('canvas-'+page_no);

            // $('#go_pdf').click();
            if (__ISMULTIPLEPAGE){
                var thisPageURL = __CANVAS.toDataURL();
                    thisPage = dataURLtoBlob(thisPageURL);
                    __MULTIPAGEHOLDER.push(thisPage);

                if (__MULTIPAGEHOLDER.length === __TOTAL_PAGES){
                    // Once all blob are ready then only will submit to backend
                    submitPDFtoBackend(__MULTIPAGEHOLDER);
                }
            } else {
                var pdfData = [];
                if (pdfCanvas != null) {
                    var data = __CANVAS.toDataURL();
                    pdfData.push(dataURLtoBlob(data));
                }

                submitPDFtoBackend(pdfData);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But the above didn't work to my expectation, because at times, the submitPDFtoBackend method will still be called even if toDataURL is still running. I only want the submitPDFtoBackend to be called only after all toDataURL has been completed, and all blobs have been pushed to the array.

I'd read about making toDataURL processes as a promise, therefore can execute the submit method on the promises using $.when but i'm not sure if that is feasible. Something like

```
$.when.apply(null, promise).then(function() {
    submitPDFtoBackend(__MULTIPAGEHOLDER);
});
```

But i'm not sure on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of going to dateURL and then from there to blob, you can go to blob directly by canvas.toBlob
2. To check if the blob is ready you can trap it in the onload handler of an img element then call submitPDFToBackend within the onload handler. Below snippet directly from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
var newImg = document.createElement('img'),
url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
newImg.onload = function() {
// no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
newImg.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(newImg);
```

});